# When does the NMOS form the channel? VGS > VTH or VGB > VTH?

Tags: cmos

[image: NMOS]

When does the NMOS form the channel? VGS > VTH or VGB > VTH?
I see that textbook talks about VGS > VTH, channel formed,  but the capacitor is formed between the gate and the body, so i think it should be VGB >VTH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *When does the NMOS form the channel?*

An n-channel mosfet forms channel when 
$$V_{GS} > V_{TS}\tag1$$ or when $$V_{GB} > V_{TS} + V_{SB}\tag2$$
(Both conditions are actually same)

Where \$V_{TS}\$ is the threshold voltage with source as reference terminal and is given by:
$$V_{TS} = V_{T0} + \gamma(\sqrt{\phi_t+V_{SB}}-\sqrt{\phi_t})$$

\$\gamma\$ and \$\phi_t\$ are device parameters (see [body effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_voltage#Body_effect)). \$V_{T0}\$ is the threshold voltage with source and bulk shorted (\$V_{SB}=0\$). The threshold voltage given in datasheet is \$V_{T0}\$ .

The point I want to make is that you can not say that a mosfet will form channel if either \$V_{GS}\$ is greater than a particular voltage or \$V_{GB}\$ is greater than a particular voltage without the knowing the voltage between source and bulk, \$V_{SB}\$.

For example, for an n-MOS of threshold voltage 3V, \$V_{GB} = 4V\$ does not ensure channel formation if source terminal is at a higher potential than bulk (or body) terminal.

> *With respect to which reference terminal threshold voltage is defined?*

One can actually defined two threshold voltages- \$V_{TS}\$ with respect to source and \$V_{TB} (= V_{TS} + V_{SB})\$ with respect to bulk. Text books and articles, especially circuit related, usually defines it with respect to source terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed Vbg > Vth is really the condition above which a channel is formed.

I think that in the case that Vgs > Vth is used, the simple explanation is that it is assumed that the Source is shorted to the Bulk so: Vgs = Vgb

When the source is not shorted to Bulk and Vsb > 0 body effect will increase Vth so I think using Vbg > Vth is prefered.